# Connect BonitaBPM to Alfresco repository

Tags: upload, alfresco, business-process-management, bonita

I'm new to Bonita and Alfresco.

I want to upload a file through a form and store it in an Alfresco folder.

So, I created a task with a form where the user would upload a file and the same task has a connector to alfresco 4.2.

When I run the process, and I click the "Soumettre" button in the portal, I get the following error message:
**"Erreur lors de la soumission du formulaire."** which can be translated to "An error has occured while submitting the form." (I swear I didn't use Google Translate :D).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I'm using Bonita v6.5.0 and Alfresco v4.2e

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I had a data "file" associated to the whole pool which was not used and it was causing this ambiguous problem... I just had to delete it.

Hope this could help someone.